# Depedency in inner view

Tags: xamarin, prism

How I can resolve my dependencies in inner ViewModel?

I create page xaml page "p1" and add inner contentview "p2"

Then, I created p2ViewMovel and this work. But when I added a dependency "IEventAggregator" in p2ViewMovel and get null reference exception.

What I doing wrong?

/Views/p1.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Tests.Views;assembly=Tests.Shell"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="Tests.Views.p1">
    <StackLayout>
        <views:p2 />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

/Views/p2.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="Tests.Views.p2">
    <Label Text="{Binding Text}" />
</ContentView>
```

/ViewModels/p1ViewModel.cs

```
public class p1ViewModel : BindableBase, INavigationAware {
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;

    public p1ViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationParameters parameters) {}

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters) {
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<t>().Publish("p1");
    }
}
```

/ViewModels/p2ViewModel.cs

```
public class p2ViewModel : BindableBase {
    private readonly IEventAggregator _eventAggregator;
    private string _text = "p2";

    public p2ViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) {
        _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<t>().Subscribe(s => Text = s);

    }

    public string Text {
        get { return _text; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _text, value); }
    }
}
```

/PubSubEvents/t.cs

```
public class t : PubSubEvent<string> {}
```

If I remove

```
public p2ViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator) {
    _eventAggregator = eventAggregator;
    _eventAggregator.GetEvent<t>().Subscribe(s => Text = s);
}
```

All work fine

Comment: Please, edit your question to include your code. Give an indication of where the error is occurring. This will help us help you.

Comment: How do you create the view models? If you create them yourself by using `new`, you have to pass in the dependencies, that is, dependencies of sub-objects become dependencies of the owning object.

Comment: ViewModel created by
`prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"` in xaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was here [ViewModelLocationProvider.cs](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/09adc93648552c70a948ceed02b5fdf216a8169a/Source/Prism/Mvvm/ViewModelLocationProvider.cs#L35). Prism not use DI container as default. Or here [UnityBootstrapper.cs](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/1672a0b4635de6a2bfdda7892347c8c1d61c9d7e/Source/Xamarin/Prism.Unity.Forms/PrismApplication.cs#L41). Prism can't resolve inner ViewModel by container and use Activator.CreateInstance

My problem was solved by direct registarion

```
ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<p2>(() => Container.Resolve<p2ViewModel>());
```

For support navigation I add registration

```
Container.RegisterType<INavigationService, UnityPageNavigationService>( new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

don't know why UnityBootstrapper don't doing that.

Comment: What version of Prism are you using?